# Error in gym.make Gym no longer distributes ROMs

Tags: python

I am running `gym` on Linux and with the following dependencies with python version `3.8.10`:

```
ale-py==0.8.1
pyglet==2.0.5
gym[atari]==0.26.2
autorom[accept-rom-license]==0.6.1
```

Whenever I run

```
import gym
gym.make("ALE/Pong-v5")
```

I get the following error:

gym.error.Error: We're Unable to find the game "Pong". Note: Gym no longer distributes
ROMs. If you own a license to use the necessary ROMs for research purposes you can
download them via `pip install gym[accept-rom-license]`. Otherwise, you should try
importing "Pong" via the command `ale-import-roms`. If you believe this is a mistake
perhaps your copy of "Pong" is unsupported. To check if this is the case try providing
the environment variable `PYTHONWARNINGS=default::ImportWarning:ale_py.roms`. For more
information see: https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment#rom-
management

I checked the list of environments and ALE/Pong-v5 is already in the list below. What can be the cause of the problem? Thank you.

from gym import envs
envs.registry.keys()

```
from gym import envs
envs.registry.keys()
```

dict_keys(['ALE/Adventure-v5', 'ALE/Adventure-ram-v5', 'ALE/AirRaid-v5', 'ALE/AirRaid-ram-v5', 'ALE/Alien-v5', 'ALE/Alien-ram-v5', 'ALE/Amidar-v5', 'ALE/Amidar-ram-v5', 'ALE/Assault-v5', 'ALE/Assault-ram-v5', 'ALE/Asterix-v5', 'ALE/Asterix-ram-v5', 'ALE/Asteroids-v5', 'ALE/Asteroids-ram-v5', 'ALE/Atlantis-v5', 'ALE/Atlantis-ram-v5', 'ALE/Atlantis2-v5', 'ALE/Atlantis2-ram-v5', 'ALE/Backgammon-v5', 'ALE/Backgammon-ram-v5', 'ALE/BankHeist-v5', 'ALE/BankHeist-ram-v5', 'ALE/BasicMath-v5', 'ALE/BasicMath-ram-v5', 'ALE/BattleZone-v5', 'ALE/BattleZone-ram-v5', 'ALE/BeamRider-v5', 'ALE/BeamRider-ram-v5', 'ALE/Berzerk-v5', 'ALE/Berzerk-ram-v5', 'ALE/Blackjack-v5', 'ALE/Blackjack-ram-v5', 'ALE/Bowling-v5', 'ALE/Bowling-ram-v5', 'ALE/Boxing-v5', 'ALE/Boxing-ram-v5', 'ALE/Breakout-v5', 'ALE/Breakout-ram-v5', 'ALE/Carnival-v5', 'ALE/Carnival-ram-v5', 'ALE/Casino-v5', 'ALE/Casino-ram-v5', 'ALE/Centipede-v5', 'ALE/Centipede-ram-v5', 'ALE/ChopperCommand-v5', 'ALE/ChopperCommand-ram-v5', 'ALE/CrazyClimber-v5', 'ALE/CrazyClimber-ram-v5', 'ALE/Crossbow-v5', 'ALE/Crossbow-ram-v5', 'ALE/Darkchambers-v5', 'ALE/Darkchambers-ram-v5', 'ALE/Defender-v5', 'ALE/Defender-ram-v5', 'ALE/DemonAttack-v5', 'ALE/DemonAttack-ram-v5', 'ALE/DonkeyKong-v5', 'ALE/DonkeyKong-ram-v5', 'ALE/DoubleDunk-v5', 'ALE/DoubleDunk-ram-v5', 'ALE/Earthworld-v5', 'ALE/Earthworld-ram-v5', 'ALE/ElevatorAction-v5', 'ALE/ElevatorAction-ram-v5', 'ALE/Enduro-v5', 'ALE/Enduro-ram-v5', 'ALE/Entombed-v5', 'ALE/Entombed-ram-v5', 'ALE/Et-v5', 'ALE/Et-ram-v5', 'ALE/FishingDerby-v5', 'ALE/FishingDerby-ram-v5', 'ALE/FlagCapture-v5', 'ALE/FlagCapture-ram-v5', 'ALE/Freeway-v5', 'ALE/Freeway-ram-v5', 'ALE/Frogger-v5', 'ALE/Frogger-ram-v5', 'ALE/Frostbite-v5', 'ALE/Frostbite-ram-v5', 'ALE/Galaxian-v5', 'ALE/Galaxian-ram-v5', 'ALE/Gopher-v5', 'ALE/Gopher-ram-v5', 'ALE/Gravitar-v5', 'ALE/Gravitar-ram-v5', 'ALE/Hangman-v5', 'ALE/Hangman-ram-v5', 'ALE/HauntedHouse-v5', 'ALE/HauntedHouse-ram-v5', 'ALE/Hero-v5', 'ALE/Hero-ram-v5', 'ALE/HumanCannonball-v5', 'ALE/HumanCannonball-ram-v5', 'ALE/IceHockey-v5', 'ALE/IceHockey-ram-v5', 'ALE/Jamesbond-v5', 'ALE/Jamesbond-ram-v5', 'ALE/JourneyEscape-v5', 'ALE/JourneyEscape-ram-v5', 'ALE/Kaboom-v5', 'ALE/Kaboom-ram-v5', 'ALE/Kangaroo-v5', 'ALE/Kangaroo-ram-v5', 'ALE/KeystoneKapers-v5', 'ALE/KeystoneKapers-ram-v5', 'ALE/KingKong-v5', 'ALE/KingKong-ram-v5', 'ALE/Klax-v5', 'ALE/Klax-ram-v5', 'ALE/Koolaid-v5', 'ALE/Koolaid-ram-v5', 'ALE/Krull-v5', 'ALE/Krull-ram-v5', 'ALE/KungFuMaster-v5', 'ALE/KungFuMaster-ram-v5', 'ALE/LaserGates-v5', 'ALE/LaserGates-ram-v5', 'ALE/LostLuggage-v5', 'ALE/LostLuggage-ram-v5', 'ALE/MarioBros-v5', 'ALE/MarioBros-ram-v5', 'ALE/MiniatureGolf-v5', 'ALE/MiniatureGolf-ram-v5', 'ALE/MontezumaRevenge-v5', 'ALE/MontezumaRevenge-ram-v5', 'ALE/MrDo-v5', 'ALE/MrDo-ram-v5', 'ALE/MsPacman-v5', 'ALE/MsPacman-ram-v5', 'ALE/NameThisGame-v5', 'ALE/NameThisGame-ram-v5', 'ALE/Othello-v5', 'ALE/Othello-ram-v5', 'ALE/Pacman-v5', 'ALE/Pacman-ram-v5', 'ALE/Phoenix-v5', 'ALE/Phoenix-ram-v5', 'ALE/Pitfall-v5', 'ALE/Pitfall-ram-v5', 'ALE/Pitfall2-v5', 'ALE/Pitfall2-ram-v5', 'ALE/Pong-v5', 'ALE/Pong-ram-v5', 'ALE/Pooyan-v5', 'ALE/Pooyan-ram-v5', 'ALE/PrivateEye-v5', 'ALE/PrivateEye-ram-v5', 'ALE/Qbert-v5', 'ALE/Qbert-ram-v5', 'ALE/Riverraid-v5', 'ALE/Riverraid-ram-v5', 'ALE/RoadRunner-v5', 'ALE/RoadRunner-ram-v5', 'ALE/Robotank-v5', 'ALE/Robotank-ram-v5', 'ALE/Seaquest-v5', 'ALE/Seaquest-ram-v5', 'ALE/SirLancelot-v5', 'ALE/SirLancelot-ram-v5', 'ALE/Skiing-v5', 'ALE/Skiing-ram-v5', 'ALE/Solaris-v5', 'ALE/Solaris-ram-v5', 'ALE/SpaceInvaders-v5', 'ALE/SpaceInvaders-ram-v5', 'ALE/SpaceWar-v5', 'ALE/SpaceWar-ram-v5', 'ALE/StarGunner-v5', 'ALE/StarGunner-ram-v5', 'ALE/Superman-v5', 'ALE/Superman-ram-v5', 'ALE/Surround-v5', 'ALE/Surround-ram-v5', 'ALE/Tennis-v5', 'ALE/Tennis-ram-v5', 'ALE/Tetris-v5', 'ALE/Tetris-ram-v5', 'ALE/TicTacToe3D-v5', 'ALE/TicTacToe3D-ram-v5', 'ALE/TimePilot-v5', 'ALE/TimePilot-ram-v5', 'ALE/Trondead-v5', 'ALE/Trondead-ram-v5', 'ALE/Turmoil-v5', 'ALE/Turmoil-ram-v5', 'ALE/Tutankham-v5', 'ALE/Tutankham-ram-v5', 'ALE/UpNDown-v5', 'ALE/UpNDown-ram-v5', 'ALE/Venture-v5', 'ALE/Venture-ram-v5', 'ALE/VideoCheckers-v5', 'ALE/VideoCheckers-ram-v5', 'ALE/VideoChess-v5', 'ALE/VideoChess-ram-v5', 'ALE/VideoCube-v5', 'ALE/VideoCube-ram-v5', 'ALE/VideoPinball-v5', 'ALE/VideoPinball-ram-v5', 'ALE/WizardOfWor-v5', 'ALE/WizardOfWor-ram-v5', 'ALE/WordZapper-v5', 'ALE/WordZapper-ram-v5', 'ALE/YarsRevenge-v5', 'ALE/YarsRevenge-ram-v5', 'ALE/Zaxxon-v5', 'ALE/Zaxxon-ram-v5', 'Adventure-v0', 'AdventureDeterministic-v0', 'AdventureNoFrameskip-v0', 'Adventure-v4', 'AdventureDeterministic-v4', 'AdventureNoFrameskip-v4', 'Adventure-ram-v0', 'Adventure-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Adventure-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Adventure-ram-v4', 'Adventure-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Adventure-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'AirRaid-v0', 'AirRaidDeterministic-v0', 'AirRaidNoFrameskip-v0', 'AirRaid-v4', 'AirRaidDeterministic-v4', 'AirRaidNoFrameskip-v4', 'AirRaid-ram-v0', 'AirRaid-ramDeterministic-v0', 'AirRaid-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'AirRaid-ram-v4', 'AirRaid-ramDeterministic-v4', 'AirRaid-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Alien-v0', 'AlienDeterministic-v0', 'AlienNoFrameskip-v0', 'Alien-v4', 'AlienDeterministic-v4', 'AlienNoFrameskip-v4', 'Alien-ram-v0', 'Alien-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Alien-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Alien-ram-v4', 'Alien-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Alien-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Amidar-v0', 'AmidarDeterministic-v0', 'AmidarNoFrameskip-v0', 'Amidar-v4', 'AmidarDeterministic-v4', 'AmidarNoFrameskip-v4', 'Amidar-ram-v0', 'Amidar-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Amidar-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Amidar-ram-v4', 'Amidar-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Amidar-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Assault-v0', 'AssaultDeterministic-v0', 'AssaultNoFrameskip-v0', 'Assault-v4', 'AssaultDeterministic-v4', 'AssaultNoFrameskip-v4', 'Assault-ram-v0', 'Assault-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Assault-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Assault-ram-v4', 'Assault-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Assault-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Asterix-v0', 'AsterixDeterministic-v0', 'AsterixNoFrameskip-v0', 'Asterix-v4', 'AsterixDeterministic-v4', 'AsterixNoFrameskip-v4', 'Asterix-ram-v0', 'Asterix-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Asterix-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Asterix-ram-v4', 'Asterix-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Asterix-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Asteroids-v0', 'AsteroidsDeterministic-v0', 'AsteroidsNoFrameskip-v0', 'Asteroids-v4', 'AsteroidsDeterministic-v4', 'AsteroidsNoFrameskip-v4', 'Asteroids-ram-v0', 'Asteroids-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Asteroids-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Asteroids-ram-v4', 'Asteroids-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Asteroids-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Atlantis-v0', 'AtlantisDeterministic-v0', 'AtlantisNoFrameskip-v0', 'Atlantis-v4', 'AtlantisDeterministic-v4', 'AtlantisNoFrameskip-v4', 'Atlantis-ram-v0', 'Atlantis-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Atlantis-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Atlantis-ram-v4', 'Atlantis-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Atlantis-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'BankHeist-v0', 'BankHeistDeterministic-v0', 'BankHeistNoFrameskip-v0', 'BankHeist-v4', 'BankHeistDeterministic-v4', 'BankHeistNoFrameskip-v4', 'BankHeist-ram-v0', 'BankHeist-ramDeterministic-v0', 'BankHeist-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'BankHeist-ram-v4', 'BankHeist-ramDeterministic-v4', 'BankHeist-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'BattleZone-v0', 'BattleZoneDeterministic-v0', 'BattleZoneNoFrameskip-v0', 'BattleZone-v4', 'BattleZoneDeterministic-v4', 'BattleZoneNoFrameskip-v4', 'BattleZone-ram-v0', 'BattleZone-ramDeterministic-v0', 'BattleZone-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'BattleZone-ram-v4', 'BattleZone-ramDeterministic-v4', 'BattleZone-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'BeamRider-v0', 'BeamRiderDeterministic-v0', 'BeamRiderNoFrameskip-v0', 'BeamRider-v4', 'BeamRiderDeterministic-v4', 'BeamRiderNoFrameskip-v4', 'BeamRider-ram-v0', 'BeamRider-ramDeterministic-v0', 'BeamRider-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'BeamRider-ram-v4', 'BeamRider-ramDeterministic-v4', 'BeamRider-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Berzerk-v0', 'BerzerkDeterministic-v0', 'BerzerkNoFrameskip-v0', 'Berzerk-v4', 'BerzerkDeterministic-v4', 'BerzerkNoFrameskip-v4', 'Berzerk-ram-v0', 'Berzerk-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Berzerk-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Berzerk-ram-v4', 'Berzerk-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Berzerk-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Bowling-v0', 'BowlingDeterministic-v0', 'BowlingNoFrameskip-v0', 'Bowling-v4', 'BowlingDeterministic-v4', 'BowlingNoFrameskip-v4', 'Bowling-ram-v0', 'Bowling-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Bowling-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Bowling-ram-v4', 'Bowling-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Bowling-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Boxing-v0', 'BoxingDeterministic-v0', 'BoxingNoFrameskip-v0', 'Boxing-v4', 'BoxingDeterministic-v4', 'BoxingNoFrameskip-v4', 'Boxing-ram-v0', 'Boxing-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Boxing-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Boxing-ram-v4', 'Boxing-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Boxing-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Breakout-v0', 'BreakoutDeterministic-v0', 'BreakoutNoFrameskip-v0', 'Breakout-v4', 'BreakoutDeterministic-v4', 'BreakoutNoFrameskip-v4', 'Breakout-ram-v0', 'Breakout-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Breakout-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Breakout-ram-v4', 'Breakout-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Breakout-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Carnival-v0', 'CarnivalDeterministic-v0', 'CarnivalNoFrameskip-v0', 'Carnival-v4', 'CarnivalDeterministic-v4', 'CarnivalNoFrameskip-v4', 'Carnival-ram-v0', 'Carnival-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Carnival-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Carnival-ram-v4', 'Carnival-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Carnival-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Centipede-v0', 'CentipedeDeterministic-v0', 'CentipedeNoFrameskip-v0', 'Centipede-v4', 'CentipedeDeterministic-v4', 'CentipedeNoFrameskip-v4', 'Centipede-ram-v0', 'Centipede-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Centipede-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Centipede-ram-v4', 'Centipede-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Centipede-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'ChopperCommand-v0', 'ChopperCommandDeterministic-v0', 'ChopperCommandNoFrameskip-v0', 'ChopperCommand-v4', 'ChopperCommandDeterministic-v4', 'ChopperCommandNoFrameskip-v4', 'ChopperCommand-ram-v0', 'ChopperCommand-ramDeterministic-v0', 'ChopperCommand-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'ChopperCommand-ram-v4', 'ChopperCommand-ramDeterministic-v4', 'ChopperCommand-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'CrazyClimber-v0', 'CrazyClimberDeterministic-v0', 'CrazyClimberNoFrameskip-v0', 'CrazyClimber-v4', 'CrazyClimberDeterministic-v4', 'CrazyClimberNoFrameskip-v4', 'CrazyClimber-ram-v0', 'CrazyClimber-ramDeterministic-v0', 'CrazyClimber-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'CrazyClimber-ram-v4', 'CrazyClimber-ramDeterministic-v4', 'CrazyClimber-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Defender-v0', 'DefenderDeterministic-v0', 'DefenderNoFrameskip-v0', 'Defender-v4', 'DefenderDeterministic-v4', 'DefenderNoFrameskip-v4', 'Defender-ram-v0', 'Defender-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Defender-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Defender-ram-v4', 'Defender-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Defender-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'DemonAttack-v0', 'DemonAttackDeterministic-v0', 'DemonAttackNoFrameskip-v0', 'DemonAttack-v4', 'DemonAttackDeterministic-v4', 'DemonAttackNoFrameskip-v4', 'DemonAttack-ram-v0', 'DemonAttack-ramDeterministic-v0', 'DemonAttack-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'DemonAttack-ram-v4', 'DemonAttack-ramDeterministic-v4', 'DemonAttack-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'DoubleDunk-v0', 'DoubleDunkDeterministic-v0', 'DoubleDunkNoFrameskip-v0', 'DoubleDunk-v4', 'DoubleDunkDeterministic-v4', 'DoubleDunkNoFrameskip-v4', 'DoubleDunk-ram-v0', 'DoubleDunk-ramDeterministic-v0', 'DoubleDunk-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'DoubleDunk-ram-v4', 'DoubleDunk-ramDeterministic-v4', 'DoubleDunk-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'ElevatorAction-v0', 'ElevatorActionDeterministic-v0', 'ElevatorActionNoFrameskip-v0', 'ElevatorAction-v4', 'ElevatorActionDeterministic-v4', 'ElevatorActionNoFrameskip-v4', 'ElevatorAction-ram-v0', 'ElevatorAction-ramDeterministic-v0', 'ElevatorAction-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'ElevatorAction-ram-v4', 'ElevatorAction-ramDeterministic-v4', 'ElevatorAction-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Enduro-v0', 'EnduroDeterministic-v0', 'EnduroNoFrameskip-v0', 'Enduro-v4', 'EnduroDeterministic-v4', 'EnduroNoFrameskip-v4', 'Enduro-ram-v0', 'Enduro-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Enduro-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Enduro-ram-v4', 'Enduro-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Enduro-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'FishingDerby-v0', 'FishingDerbyDeterministic-v0', 'FishingDerbyNoFrameskip-v0', 'FishingDerby-v4', 'FishingDerbyDeterministic-v4', 'FishingDerbyNoFrameskip-v4', 'FishingDerby-ram-v0', 'FishingDerby-ramDeterministic-v0', 'FishingDerby-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'FishingDerby-ram-v4', 'FishingDerby-ramDeterministic-v4', 'FishingDerby-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Freeway-v0', 'FreewayDeterministic-v0', 'FreewayNoFrameskip-v0', 'Freeway-v4', 'FreewayDeterministic-v4', 'FreewayNoFrameskip-v4', 'Freeway-ram-v0', 'Freeway-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Freeway-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Freeway-ram-v4', 'Freeway-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Freeway-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Frostbite-v0', 'FrostbiteDeterministic-v0', 'FrostbiteNoFrameskip-v0', 'Frostbite-v4', 'FrostbiteDeterministic-v4', 'FrostbiteNoFrameskip-v4', 'Frostbite-ram-v0', 'Frostbite-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Frostbite-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Frostbite-ram-v4', 'Frostbite-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Frostbite-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Gopher-v0', 'GopherDeterministic-v0', 'GopherNoFrameskip-v0', 'Gopher-v4', 'GopherDeterministic-v4', 'GopherNoFrameskip-v4', 'Gopher-ram-v0', 'Gopher-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Gopher-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Gopher-ram-v4', 'Gopher-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Gopher-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Gravitar-v0', 'GravitarDeterministic-v0', 'GravitarNoFrameskip-v0', 'Gravitar-v4', 'GravitarDeterministic-v4', 'GravitarNoFrameskip-v4', 'Gravitar-ram-v0', 'Gravitar-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Gravitar-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Gravitar-ram-v4', 'Gravitar-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Gravitar-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Hero-v0', 'HeroDeterministic-v0', 'HeroNoFrameskip-v0', 'Hero-v4', 'HeroDeterministic-v4', 'HeroNoFrameskip-v4', 'Hero-ram-v0', 'Hero-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Hero-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Hero-ram-v4', 'Hero-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Hero-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'IceHockey-v0', 'IceHockeyDeterministic-v0', 'IceHockeyNoFrameskip-v0', 'IceHockey-v4', 'IceHockeyDeterministic-v4', 'IceHockeyNoFrameskip-v4', 'IceHockey-ram-v0', 'IceHockey-ramDeterministic-v0', 'IceHockey-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'IceHockey-ram-v4', 'IceHockey-ramDeterministic-v4', 'IceHockey-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Jamesbond-v0', 'JamesbondDeterministic-v0', 'JamesbondNoFrameskip-v0', 'Jamesbond-v4', 'JamesbondDeterministic-v4', 'JamesbondNoFrameskip-v4', 'Jamesbond-ram-v0', 'Jamesbond-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Jamesbond-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Jamesbond-ram-v4', 'Jamesbond-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Jamesbond-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'JourneyEscape-v0', 'JourneyEscapeDeterministic-v0', 'JourneyEscapeNoFrameskip-v0', 'JourneyEscape-v4', 'JourneyEscapeDeterministic-v4', 'JourneyEscapeNoFrameskip-v4', 'JourneyEscape-ram-v0', 'JourneyEscape-ramDeterministic-v0', 'JourneyEscape-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'JourneyEscape-ram-v4', 'JourneyEscape-ramDeterministic-v4', 'JourneyEscape-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Kangaroo-v0', 'KangarooDeterministic-v0', 'KangarooNoFrameskip-v0', 'Kangaroo-v4', 'KangarooDeterministic-v4', 'KangarooNoFrameskip-v4', 'Kangaroo-ram-v0', 'Kangaroo-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Kangaroo-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Kangaroo-ram-v4', 'Kangaroo-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Kangaroo-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Krull-v0', 'KrullDeterministic-v0', 'KrullNoFrameskip-v0', 'Krull-v4', 'KrullDeterministic-v4', 'KrullNoFrameskip-v4', 'Krull-ram-v0', 'Krull-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Krull-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Krull-ram-v4', 'Krull-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Krull-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'KungFuMaster-v0', 'KungFuMasterDeterministic-v0', 'KungFuMasterNoFrameskip-v0', 'KungFuMaster-v4', 'KungFuMasterDeterministic-v4', 'KungFuMasterNoFrameskip-v4', 'KungFuMaster-ram-v0', 'KungFuMaster-ramDeterministic-v0', 'KungFuMaster-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'KungFuMaster-ram-v4', 'KungFuMaster-ramDeterministic-v4', 'KungFuMaster-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'MontezumaRevenge-v0', 'MontezumaRevengeDeterministic-v0', 'MontezumaRevengeNoFrameskip-v0', 'MontezumaRevenge-v4', 'MontezumaRevengeDeterministic-v4', 'MontezumaRevengeNoFrameskip-v4', 'MontezumaRevenge-ram-v0', 'MontezumaRevenge-ramDeterministic-v0', 'MontezumaRevenge-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'MontezumaRevenge-ram-v4', 'MontezumaRevenge-ramDeterministic-v4', 'MontezumaRevenge-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'MsPacman-v0', 'MsPacmanDeterministic-v0', 'MsPacmanNoFrameskip-v0', 'MsPacman-v4', 'MsPacmanDeterministic-v4', 'MsPacmanNoFrameskip-v4', 'MsPacman-ram-v0', 'MsPacman-ramDeterministic-v0', 'MsPacman-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'MsPacman-ram-v4', 'MsPacman-ramDeterministic-v4', 'MsPacman-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'NameThisGame-v0', 'NameThisGameDeterministic-v0', 'NameThisGameNoFrameskip-v0', 'NameThisGame-v4', 'NameThisGameDeterministic-v4', 'NameThisGameNoFrameskip-v4', 'NameThisGame-ram-v0', 'NameThisGame-ramDeterministic-v0', 'NameThisGame-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'NameThisGame-ram-v4', 'NameThisGame-ramDeterministic-v4', 'NameThisGame-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Phoenix-v0', 'PhoenixDeterministic-v0', 'PhoenixNoFrameskip-v0', 'Phoenix-v4', 'PhoenixDeterministic-v4', 'PhoenixNoFrameskip-v4', 'Phoenix-ram-v0', 'Phoenix-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Phoenix-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Phoenix-ram-v4', 'Phoenix-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Phoenix-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Pitfall-v0', 'PitfallDeterministic-v0', 'PitfallNoFrameskip-v0', 'Pitfall-v4', 'PitfallDeterministic-v4', 'PitfallNoFrameskip-v4', 'Pitfall-ram-v0', 'Pitfall-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Pitfall-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Pitfall-ram-v4', 'Pitfall-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Pitfall-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Pong-v0', 'PongDeterministic-v0', 'PongNoFrameskip-v0', 'Pong-v4', 'PongDeterministic-v4', 'PongNoFrameskip-v4', 'Pong-ram-v0', 'Pong-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Pong-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Pong-ram-v4', 'Pong-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Pong-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Pooyan-v0', 'PooyanDeterministic-v0', 'PooyanNoFrameskip-v0', 'Pooyan-v4', 'PooyanDeterministic-v4', 'PooyanNoFrameskip-v4', 'Pooyan-ram-v0', 'Pooyan-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Pooyan-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Pooyan-ram-v4', 'Pooyan-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Pooyan-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'PrivateEye-v0', 'PrivateEyeDeterministic-v0', 'PrivateEyeNoFrameskip-v0', 'PrivateEye-v4', 'PrivateEyeDeterministic-v4', 'PrivateEyeNoFrameskip-v4', 'PrivateEye-ram-v0', 'PrivateEye-ramDeterministic-v0', 'PrivateEye-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'PrivateEye-ram-v4', 'PrivateEye-ramDeterministic-v4', 'PrivateEye-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Qbert-v0', 'QbertDeterministic-v0', 'QbertNoFrameskip-v0', 'Qbert-v4', 'QbertDeterministic-v4', 'QbertNoFrameskip-v4', 'Qbert-ram-v0', 'Qbert-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Qbert-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Qbert-ram-v4', 'Qbert-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Qbert-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Riverraid-v0', 'RiverraidDeterministic-v0', 'RiverraidNoFrameskip-v0', 'Riverraid-v4', 'RiverraidDeterministic-v4', 'RiverraidNoFrameskip-v4', 'Riverraid-ram-v0', 'Riverraid-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Riverraid-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Riverraid-ram-v4', 'Riverraid-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Riverraid-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'RoadRunner-v0', 'RoadRunnerDeterministic-v0', 'RoadRunnerNoFrameskip-v0', 'RoadRunner-v4', 'RoadRunnerDeterministic-v4', 'RoadRunnerNoFrameskip-v4', 'RoadRunner-ram-v0', 'RoadRunner-ramDeterministic-v0', 'RoadRunner-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'RoadRunner-ram-v4', 'RoadRunner-ramDeterministic-v4', 'RoadRunner-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Robotank-v0', 'RobotankDeterministic-v0', 'RobotankNoFrameskip-v0', 'Robotank-v4', 'RobotankDeterministic-v4', 'RobotankNoFrameskip-v4', 'Robotank-ram-v0', 'Robotank-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Robotank-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Robotank-ram-v4', 'Robotank-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Robotank-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Seaquest-v0', 'SeaquestDeterministic-v0', 'SeaquestNoFrameskip-v0', 'Seaquest-v4', 'SeaquestDeterministic-v4', 'SeaquestNoFrameskip-v4', 'Seaquest-ram-v0', 'Seaquest-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Seaquest-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Seaquest-ram-v4', 'Seaquest-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Seaquest-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Skiing-v0', 'SkiingDeterministic-v0', 'SkiingNoFrameskip-v0', 'Skiing-v4', 'SkiingDeterministic-v4', 'SkiingNoFrameskip-v4', 'Skiing-ram-v0', 'Skiing-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Skiing-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Skiing-ram-v4', 'Skiing-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Skiing-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Solaris-v0', 'SolarisDeterministic-v0', 'SolarisNoFrameskip-v0', 'Solaris-v4', 'SolarisDeterministic-v4', 'SolarisNoFrameskip-v4', 'Solaris-ram-v0', 'Solaris-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Solaris-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Solaris-ram-v4', 'Solaris-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Solaris-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'SpaceInvaders-v0', 'SpaceInvadersDeterministic-v0', 'SpaceInvadersNoFrameskip-v0', 'SpaceInvaders-v4', 'SpaceInvadersDeterministic-v4', 'SpaceInvadersNoFrameskip-v4', 'SpaceInvaders-ram-v0', 'SpaceInvaders-ramDeterministic-v0', 'SpaceInvaders-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'SpaceInvaders-ram-v4', 'SpaceInvaders-ramDeterministic-v4', 'SpaceInvaders-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'StarGunner-v0', 'StarGunnerDeterministic-v0', 'StarGunnerNoFrameskip-v0', 'StarGunner-v4', 'StarGunnerDeterministic-v4', 'StarGunnerNoFrameskip-v4', 'StarGunner-ram-v0', 'StarGunner-ramDeterministic-v0', 'StarGunner-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'StarGunner-ram-v4', 'StarGunner-ramDeterministic-v4', 'StarGunner-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Tennis-v0', 'TennisDeterministic-v0', 'TennisNoFrameskip-v0', 'Tennis-v4', 'TennisDeterministic-v4', 'TennisNoFrameskip-v4', 'Tennis-ram-v0', 'Tennis-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Tennis-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Tennis-ram-v4', 'Tennis-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Tennis-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'TimePilot-v0', 'TimePilotDeterministic-v0', 'TimePilotNoFrameskip-v0', 'TimePilot-v4', 'TimePilotDeterministic-v4', 'TimePilotNoFrameskip-v4', 'TimePilot-ram-v0', 'TimePilot-ramDeterministic-v0', 'TimePilot-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'TimePilot-ram-v4', 'TimePilot-ramDeterministic-v4', 'TimePilot-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Tutankham-v0', 'TutankhamDeterministic-v0', 'TutankhamNoFrameskip-v0', 'Tutankham-v4', 'TutankhamDeterministic-v4', 'TutankhamNoFrameskip-v4', 'Tutankham-ram-v0', 'Tutankham-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Tutankham-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Tutankham-ram-v4', 'Tutankham-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Tutankham-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'UpNDown-v0', 'UpNDownDeterministic-v0', 'UpNDownNoFrameskip-v0', 'UpNDown-v4', 'UpNDownDeterministic-v4', 'UpNDownNoFrameskip-v4', 'UpNDown-ram-v0', 'UpNDown-ramDeterministic-v0', 'UpNDown-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'UpNDown-ram-v4', 'UpNDown-ramDeterministic-v4', 'UpNDown-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Venture-v0', 'VentureDeterministic-v0', 'VentureNoFrameskip-v0', 'Venture-v4', 'VentureDeterministic-v4', 'VentureNoFrameskip-v4', 'Venture-ram-v0', 'Venture-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Venture-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Venture-ram-v4', 'Venture-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Venture-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'VideoPinball-v0', 'VideoPinballDeterministic-v0', 'VideoPinballNoFrameskip-v0', 'VideoPinball-v4', 'VideoPinballDeterministic-v4', 'VideoPinballNoFrameskip-v4', 'VideoPinball-ram-v0', 'VideoPinball-ramDeterministic-v0', 'VideoPinball-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'VideoPinball-ram-v4', 'VideoPinball-ramDeterministic-v4', 'VideoPinball-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'WizardOfWor-v0', 'WizardOfWorDeterministic-v0', 'WizardOfWorNoFrameskip-v0', 'WizardOfWor-v4', 'WizardOfWorDeterministic-v4', 'WizardOfWorNoFrameskip-v4', 'WizardOfWor-ram-v0', 'WizardOfWor-ramDeterministic-v0', 'WizardOfWor-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'WizardOfWor-ram-v4', 'WizardOfWor-ramDeterministic-v4', 'WizardOfWor-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'YarsRevenge-v0', 'YarsRevengeDeterministic-v0', 'YarsRevengeNoFrameskip-v0', 'YarsRevenge-v4', 'YarsRevengeDeterministic-v4', 'YarsRevengeNoFrameskip-v4', 'YarsRevenge-ram-v0', 'YarsRevenge-ramDeterministic-v0', 'YarsRevenge-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'YarsRevenge-ram-v4', 'YarsRevenge-ramDeterministic-v4', 'YarsRevenge-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'Zaxxon-v0', 'ZaxxonDeterministic-v0', 'ZaxxonNoFrameskip-v0', 'Zaxxon-v4', 'ZaxxonDeterministic-v4', 'ZaxxonNoFrameskip-v4', 'Zaxxon-ram-v0', 'Zaxxon-ramDeterministic-v0', 'Zaxxon-ramNoFrameskip-v0', 'Zaxxon-ram-v4', 'Zaxxon-ramDeterministic-v4', 'Zaxxon-ramNoFrameskip-v4', 'CartPole-v0', 'CartPole-v1', 'MountainCar-v0', 'MountainCarContinuous-v0', 'Pendulum-v1', 'Acrobot-v1', 'LunarLander-v2', 'LunarLanderContinuous-v2', 'BipedalWalker-v3', 'BipedalWalkerHardcore-v3', 'CarRacing-v2', 'Blackjack-v1', 'FrozenLake-v1', 'FrozenLake8x8-v1', 'CliffWalking-v0', 'Taxi-v3', 'Reacher-v2', 'Reacher-v4', 'Pusher-v2', 'Pusher-v4', 'InvertedPendulum-v2', 'InvertedPendulum-v4', 'InvertedDoublePendulum-v2', 'InvertedDoublePendulum-v4', 'HalfCheetah-v2', 'HalfCheetah-v3', 'HalfCheetah-v4', 'Hopper-v2', 'Hopper-v3', 'Hopper-v4', 'Swimmer-v2', 'Swimmer-v3', 'Swimmer-v4', 'Walker2d-v2', 'Walker2d-v3', 'Walker2d-v4', 'Ant-v2', 'Ant-v3', 'Ant-v4', 'Humanoid-v2', 'Humanoid-v3', 'Humanoid-v4', 'HumanoidStandup-v2', 'HumanoidStandup-v4'])